# SVN view commits between tag and trunk

Tags: svn, tags, trunk

With SVN is there an easy way to get a list of all the commits between a tag (usually the most recent) and the current trunk, so you can see what (if anything) has changed?

Likewise, can you do the same to compare the commits between two tags.

Cheers, 
Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy solution. `svn log --stop-on-copy <tag-path>` will allow you to find whether the tag was made from the trunk. If yes, the you can take the copied version, and do svn log between those versions on the trunk.